# checkbox in list view in django template , retrieve all checked box objects in each pagination to view of Django (server)

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, jinja2

I have checkbox in list view and contains pagination in html template. I want to retrieve the all checked box objects in each pagination to server (view part of Django) . Example in page 1 , if i checked 4 objects , page2 checked 3 objects , page 3 checked 4 objects then finally when i clicked then i will get all 11 checked objects into the server.

[image]

I tried , But i am getting only selected objects in current page . When i navigate to next page then first selected object deleted . I don't know how to retrieve all objects together in each page .

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is not related to Django.
You have to build a system to memorize the boxes checked between pages.
On client side, you can use GET parameters or cookies to memorize boxes from one page to another.
Then in the Django view, you can get all the boxes reading GET parameters or cookies.